# Test unpublished add-on fails

Tags: gsuite-addons

I'm trying to test an unpublished Google Sheets add-on with other google accounts.
I've followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons) but it doesn't work as expected:

- In any case no "Install add-on" button is displayed for the head deployment
- In order to display the button "install as add-on", the tester needs to create a new deployment
- If the user has read-only access it shows the following error
  [image: error read only access]
- If the user has edit access, then it shows the button

Once the button is displayed, clicking on it shows a message saying that it's deploying the add-on but...

- **In no case the add-on appears in a spreadsheet, nor in the Manage add-ons pop-up**
- When I come back to the "deploy from manifest" list, the deployment that was supposed to be associated to the add-on doesn't show the expected button "uninstall add-on"

I have tried:

- with Gsuite users having editing rights and myself, the owner.
  FYI,
- with a stand-alone script and a script associate to a spreadsheet... same results

I think the whole flow is just not working. So please G Suite team check out this message